# Can a SD card change its size (capacity) over time?

Tags: sd-card

I have recently looked at the size of my various SD-cards. Though they often feature the same size on their label (like saying 8GB) I find that some show
different sizes (when looked at its details), like say (7948206080 Bytes for one and 8010072064 for another). I found out running those commands

```
blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb 
8010072064
blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdc 
7948206080
```

Now I wonder how the second 8GB SD card came to have only 7948206080 bytes. I will monitor their behaviour a little, yet I wonder (with those odd numbers for SD-Card sizes) if a I can trust that the reported size of an SD-Card will always be the same, over time?

i.o.w, I would like to know, can a SD-card (by the standard it conforms to, or by popular experience) change its size over time?

It would seem reasonable that, given wear-and-tear of the memory cells some loss of capacity would not be suprising, yet I assumed that any such failure of cells would have rather resulted in a complete failure of the card instead?

Comment: @fernando.reyes can you specify what you mean with "they being formatted in the same file system"?  The two sd cards in question have different content, yet the invocation of `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdcardX` should not be dependent on the cards content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't change size.
If a fault develops during use it is usually all or nothing and the entire card becomes unusable. The on-board controller simply doesn't have the CPU power to do something intelligent in that case.

But vendors can (and will) take some liberty with how they define the size.
It is exceedingly rare that an 8 GB card has exactly 8000000000 bytes.
Even 2 identical cards (same model) from the same vendor could have slightly different sizes if they come from different production runs. It all depends on the exact flash-chip(s) used (and this varies a lot).
It is also possible that during production part of the flash-memory was determined faulty/unusable and mapped out, making the effective size somewhat smaller than expected. If a large part is unusable it is also not unheard of to re-brand it as a half-size device. (E.g take 40% defective 16 GB flash-chip and turn the good half into a 8 GB chip.)

As long the actual size isn't less than about 95% than the expected capacity written on the packaging nobody really cares.

On my desk right now I have 2 identical 16 GB USB sticks. One is 15.7 GB according to Windows and the other is 15.8 GB.
When I look at the USB device information both sticks present themselves as exactly the same hardware to Windows, just different serial numbers and size.